# ¿Como puedo colocar el ui-jq="chosen" en un DropDownList con Razor"?

Tags: c#, razor, dropdownlist

tengo una duda.

Para colocarle la clase ya se como realizarlo pero mi duda es como llamo un ui-jq o como lo implemento

Este es ejemplo del select HTML

```
     <select ui-jq="chosen" class="w-full">
```

Y este es mi Razor donde quiero colocarle el ui-jq

```
@Html.DropDownList("Estado", listaEstados,null, new { @class = "w-full" })
```

Agradezco el apoyo anticipadamente.. Saludos